# recognize <br> tag in jquery,while looping through each node -

Tags: jquery, html, prepend

here is the problem and its really really killing me becauseit probably has a very simple solution.
check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FL2Ut/3/)

```
<body>
<p>
    this is the first paragraph and it will get the prepend without any problems at all
</p>
<span>
    this is a simple span element, and it will also get the prepend without any problems at all
</span>
<em>
    heres a em and this works as well

</em>
<p>
   here is another para and it works , BUT NOW LOOK AT THE NEXT LINE
    <br>BR STARTS HERE
        where is this prepend, ladies and gentlement,,NADA.
    </br>
</p>
```

```
$("*", document.body).each(function () {
$(this).prepend('<b><font color="red">  soccer  </font></b>');
});
```

you will find a simple set of HTML tags just a few randomly placed `<p>` and `<span>` tags.
I have written a small jquery (2 lines function) that loops through all the tags in the body of the page and prepends a piece of html to each tag.

Unfortunately, the `<br>` tags do not seem to follow what all the other tags follo. It does not get the prepended HTML and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: <br> tags are not meant to be used with a closing tag. You use it like: <br> or <br /> to break to a new line.

Comment: Your markup is invalid. BR tags can not have content, so the problem you're describing is non existent!

Comment: As @Derek said, <br> is used alone. In XHTML, you must use it as <br />. But it does not wrap content like most other tags. It operates alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because a `<br/>` tag can't have any children elements or content https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/br.. if you use .before()/.after() it will show up as a sibling as you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gmbpt/

Comment: thanks wirey,, this is what i was looking for, i needed to add something to identify each and every node in the DOM, and i was stuck on BR,,, just a small follow up qustion -- is there any other tag/tags that behave like this , that i need to watch out for,, or will .before() cover them all.

Comment: @user2076066 http://stackoverflow.com/a/7854998/1385672 - but before should cover each every tag since it's adding at the sibling level

Answer (score 0):

If you read the specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) you will see that the content model of `br` is ***empty***.

This means that it can not have contents..